# Android login rails app json params problem

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, authentication

I have an android client application, which will connect to a rails 3 web app to login and get data.

The android login code is as following:

```
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://192.168.72.132:3000/sessions.json");
StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder( "{email:" + username + ",password:" + password + "}" );       
JSONObject loginDetail = new JSONObject(jsonString.toString());
json.put("session", loginDetail);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());  
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
```

In Rails server, the json request can be obtained, but when I print out params[:session][:username] and params[:session][:password], they are both nil.

When I change:

```
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://192.168.72.132:3000/sessions.json");
```

to:

```
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://192.168.72.132:3000/sessions.json?email=test@gmail.com");
```

The params[:email] can be printed out correctly.

But I need params[:session][:email].

Is there anything I am coding wrong? And idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you make it anywhere on this question?

Answer (score 0):

I was advised to use something like OAuth for login and stay away from sessions for creating android app on rails server.